# Angular and Ajax Difference When Sending Request To NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, node.js

I am trying to use some angular to communicate with a NodeJS server.

**What I would do in JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/list",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
   console.log("data passed back from server is:" + data)
  },
  error: function(err) {
     console.log("an error occured")
     console.log(err)
  }
})
```

**What I am doing with Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "/list"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

However when using angular the browser tells me:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:3000/list
```

Am I not referencing the url correctly?

**Server**

```
   app.post('/list', function (req, res){
      // Establish connection to db
      con.query('SELECT * FROM employees',function(err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          listArray.push(rows[i])
        };
        /*
        ar names = listArray.map(function(item) {
        return item;
        });
        console.log(names)
        */
        res.send(listArray)
      })
```

Comment: Ajax is using `POST` Angular is using `GET`, node is expecting a `POST`

Comment: Oh that was the problem. the error totally threw me off though. thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your ajax call is making a `POST` request to the `/list` however in Angular you have specified `GET`

Now the node configuration is expecting a `POST` request. You should be able to simply change the angular method to `POST`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url : "/list"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

Comment: I am so embarrassed >.> <.<

Comment: No worries happens to all of us!